# Hiding election badges on beta sites badge lists

Tags: discussion, badges, election

Is there any point in showing the *Caucus* and *Constituent* badges in the list of achievable badges on beta sites that don't have elections until after they have graduated?

Comment: Yearling shows up well before the site is a year old, Archaeologist before there are 100 questions inactive for 6 months available...

Answer (score 3):

They're achievable in some theoretical future, so I think there's no harm in keeping them; plus they would provide one additional *atto*-unit of incentive to the users to help the beta graduate!